# how to modify message of one kafka topic and send to another kafka topic using java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have created producer which produces MSG to one topic A and My need is I want to do change in that MSG and want to send it to another topic B, I'm trying to do this by Kafka streams,but not sure is it a right way or not. if it requires Kafka streams for that then please share what should be the code to write?

Comment: I would use Kafka Streams for that.

Answer (score 9):

There are many options how you can to this.

Kafka's Streams API is one possibility with the advantage that you don't add a new dependency to your project. As simple `stream.map(...).to(...)` as program should do this. Check out the docs and examples for more details:

- http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html
- https://github.com/confluentinc/examples

You could even just use plain `KafkaConsumer` and `KafkaProducer` to get this done (but using Kafka's Streams API seem to be more natural than this).

Of course, you can also use a stream processing framework like Apache Flink, Apache Storm, Apache Apex, Heron (or maybe Apache Spark) -- for sure, there are others too. The program would be similarly simple to write as sketched above. But you need to setup a processing cluster to deploy you job for those stream processing framework.

Comment: @anzzý I am wondering why you did revert your accept of this answer? Can you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using [Apache storm](http://storm.apache.org/), it will be very suitable for your needs.

I have used it and it does very well and gels like water in milk with kafka. It is also very easy to implement.

Best of luck